# VBA - reversing a function

Tags: excel, function, reverse, vba

Is it possible to reverse a function in VBA - I mean getting argument/arguments of a function by its value? Of course, we must assume that no pair of the same values are assigned to different arguments/sets of arguments.
For instance:

```
Function func(arg1 As ..., arg2 As ..., ..., argn As ...) As (valType)
 func(arg1,arg2,...,argn) = ...
End Function

Sub get_argument()

Const val = ...

Workbooks(...).Worksheets(...).Cells(...,...).Value = func^(-1)(val)

End Sub
```

Comment: A function may or may not be invertible (depending on, as you say, whether there's a 1:1 or 1:n mapping between inputs and outputs), but it's down to the programmer to implement the inverse function. There's no concept of being able to call `func^(-1)(val)`.

Comment: You could try to use `Solver` *(or an equivalent)* to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that in general, this is not possible.

The closest you can get to your goal is by writing an inverse function to reverse the logic of a specific function if and only if the target function produces a unique result from its arguments.

Comment: Of course, if it was being used on a worksheet as a UDF you could locate the cell holding it and read the cell's .formula property.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation that there are no common solutions in VBA for that problem. Writing an inverse function is an option. However, because of finite number of pairs of an argument and a value as well as complicatedness of writing the new function I won't do it. I'd rather use User Defined Type.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a function is "reversable" or not highly depends on the specific function. Where some functions might be reversable others are not.

So for example a sum function cannot be reversable. If you sum up the following 5 arguments you get one solution in return.

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

but there are many possibilities to get a sum of `15` with 5 arguments. You would need to solve the equation system `15 = x₁ + x₂ + x₃ + x₄ + x₅` which is algebraically not possible.

But what you can do is using numeric algorithms (eg. using solver) to get one solution to that equation (one of the numerous possibilities). But this way you would end up with any of the possibilities not with the original one. So the Solver might end up with `3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 = 15`.

**So conclusion is:**
Unless we don't know the original function, we cannot say if it is reversable or not.